# Node - Does client side memory leak effects on server performance

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, memory-leaks

In node application, if there is any memory leak on client side (say google chrome), does it effects server performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In node application, if there is any memory leak on client side (say google chrome), does it effects server performance?

No, unless a rogue client starts making a crazy number of requests or something like that.

A high memory using client has no direct effect at all on your server.  Client and server are separate computers, on different local networks with no shared resources.